# Geoip IP Detect using php and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, geoip

I'm using Maxmind to detect IP address and show Country Code, Country name, and city name in php. 
I've no problem to show above information through GeoIP.dat, geoip.inc, geoipcity.inc and etc

I've inserted GeoIPCountryWhois.csv into my sql database,

```
$mysqli->query('DROP TABLE ip2country'); $sql=" CREATE TABLE ip2country (ip_string_lo VARCHAR(16)  NOT NULL, ip_string_hi VARCHAR(16)  NOT NULL, ip_number_lo INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ip_number_hi INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, country_code VARCHAR(2)   NOT NULL, country_name VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL)";
```

could you please tell me how to show IP information using my database?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maxmind database is balanced binary tree. It is very fast. However putting it in MySQL sometimes makes it even faster. You will need to get CSV version fom Maxmind and easyest way is to create same structure as the CSV.

Then you need to convert the IP address to number - both PHP and MySQL have function for this.

Finally you exec simple SQL and fetch the row. Maxmind CSV have blocks of IP addresses and give youvfirst and last IP address as int. Your IP must be "inside" the block, e.g. MySQL 'between'.

I personally refer putting GeoIP in Redis because then it is even faster.

---

## Update

this is what I did several years ago:

https://github.com/nmmmnu/GeoIP-Redis

I am not 100% sure, if import still work as is, but with some tweaks it will be able to import the data.

Currently, I am using nginx module that do all this automatically and give me a header in the HTTP request.

Because it is totally different approach, you can check for that solution or open new question and contact me, so I can answer there.

Comment: Share an efficient example of importing into redis via php ?

Comment: I updating the answer